# How save the value entered in the Quick Search box when turning screen

Tags: android

I implemented a quick search in my application. But when I turned the screen, the Instant Search box is destroyed.
How save the value entered in the Quick Search box when turning screen?

I need to save the value when user turned the screen. That is, the user has entered something into the search box, do not hit the Search Button and turned the screen. Need to re-run the Search Box and write in EditText Search value which we have retained.

This  works In application YouTube .
Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to save the contents in onSaveInstanceState() method and restore (if any) in onCreate() of your activity - there's a Bundle object that gets passed around for this exact purpose.

Check out this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html and this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html for more detailed info on configuration change and Activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

you can save your TextBox's value to a variable and when you return back to that page , display value from that value. so for first time it will display blank textbox & then from next time it will display the value that you entered just before hitting search button

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to save the value when user turned the screen. That is, the user has entered something into the search box, do not hit the Search Button and turned the screen. Need to re-run the Search Box and write in EditText Search value which we have retained.

Comment: its the same, I thought you have search button

Answer (score 0):

override `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and return the value that you want to retain as follows:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String myString = myOldString;
    return myString;// or return myOldString directly.
}
```

then in your `onStart()` do the following:

```
if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
        myOldString= (String) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
yourEditText.setText(myOldString);
    } else {

        myOldString = new String();
    }
```

hint: it's recommended to use `setRetainInstance(boolean)` if you are targeting *honeycomb* or later .... but this doesn't mean that `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` is deprecated.